# Обработка и модификация массивов

Tags: java

Помогите решить, пожалуйста, задачу на Java.

> Исключить все элементы, содержащие повторяющиеся цифры и сжать влево оставшиеся элементы массива.

```
public class lab2 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int n = 10, l = 0;
        int a[] = new int[n];
        int b[] = new int[n];
        boolean p = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            a[i] = (int)(Math.round(30 * Math.random()));
            System.out.print("  " + a[i]);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            if (j != i) if (a[i] == a[j]) p = true;
            if (!p) {
                b[l] = a[i];
                l++;
            }
            p = false;
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (int k = 0; k < l; k++)
        System.out.print("  " + b[k]);
    }
}
```

Вот примерный код, но выводит одинаковые элементы, а не одинаковые цифры в элементах.

Comment: Тег не соответствует вопросу.

Answer (score 1):

Вместо сжатия тут пересылка в другой массив, это может быть засчитано за ошибку. Но это уже на усмотрение преподавателя. А исправленный вариант вот:

```
public class lab2{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int n=10, l=0;
        int a[] = new int [n];
        int b[] = new int [n];
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
            a[i]=(int)(Math.round(1000*Math.random()));
            System.out.print("  "+a[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            int digits[] = new int[10];
            int num = a[i];
            for(int j=0; j<10; j++) digits[j] = 0;
            while(num > 0) {
                digits[num%10]++;
                num = num/10;
            }
            boolean p = true;
            for (int j=0; j<n; j++) p = p && (digits[j] <= 1);
            if (p) b[l++] = a[i];
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (int k=0; k<l; k++)
            System.out.print("  "+b[k]);
    }
}
```

В нём используется вспомогательный массив digit для подсчёта количества цифр в числе.

Comment: Там в digit неправильное количество цифр для числа 0 (равно 0), но на решение задачи это не влияет

Comment: А как сделать, чтобы были только двузначные цифры? Из массива выводит же те элементы, которые с неодинаковыми цифрами, нужно чтобы было наоборот!

Comment: Не понял. Двухзначные, трёхзначные -- это входные? В данном случае они получаются из Math.random() умножением на 1000. Если умножить на 100 (или 99.99999), то числа будут от 0 до 100 -- двухзначные (ну возможно ещё 100). А условие, чтобы были повторяющиеся:
`p=false; for(int j=0; j<n; j++) p = p || (digits[j] > 1);`

Comment: ну как объяснить,в общем нужно чтобы выводило на второй строке вот эти одинаковые цифры...а если элементы трехзначные то нужно чтобы все три цифры одинаковые были)

Comment: Все поняла.

Comment: В отличие от меня. Ну ладно, главное, чтобы сама поняла.